# How to filter some files out of my directory?

Tags: shell-script

I have some files in my directory. They can be classified into two categories: the files' name pattern in class one are like `1000-24-1-7-1` that have five numbers separated by four dash; the files' name pattern in class two are like `abcd-1000-24-1-7-1-efgh-ijkl` that are also separated by dash but have letters before or after or both of before and after these numbers.

My question is that how to filter these files in class one out of my directory by moving them into a directory named by `first-class`.

Comment: Are there non-regular files (pipes, directories…) in that directory with that naming scheme? If so, do you want them to be moved, too ([Bjorn's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197246/20714) and [Eric's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197247/20714) answers), or do you want them to stay ([Don's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197288/20714) answer)?

Comment: @BlacklightShining No, these files are all regular. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some shells, you could use extended globbing+certain flags to match only files in *class one*.
With `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
for one in +([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9])
    do
        [[ -f $one ]] && mv -- "$one" first-class
    done
```

`+(<PATTERN>)` matches one or more occurrences of the given pattern, `[[ -f ... ]]` tests for regular file - if yes, it's `mv`-ed to `first-class`; to perform a *dry-run*, add `echo` in front of `mv`.

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extended_glob
mv -t first-class [0-9]##(-[0-9]##)(#c4)(.)
```

`x##` matches one or more occurrences of the pattern `x`, `(#cN)` requires exactly `N` matches and `(.)` matches only files
or:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -Q '[0-9]##(-[0-9]##)(#c4)(.)' first-class
```

`-Q` turns on bare glob qualifiers, to *dry-run* add `-n` e.g. `zmv -Qn ...`

---

If filtering regular files isn't needed then you can do without the testing in `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv -- +([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9]) first-class
```

and without the `(.)` qualifier in `zsh`:

```
setopt extended_glob
mv -t first-class [0-9]##(-[0-9]##)(#c4)
```

or

```
autoload zmv
zmv '[0-9]##(-[0-9]##)(#c4)' first-class
```

Comment: You don't need `zmv`; you can `setopt extended_glob` and use that same glob pattern with plain `mv` (or any other program, for that matter). Personally, I would use `mv` with the `-t` option.

Comment: @BlacklightShining - correct, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Also maybe worth noting that the `--` tells `mv` that there will be no further options (thus you can rename a file called `-foo` with `mv -- -foo bar`). This means that, in general, you should use `--` in scripts; it also means that it's not necessary in this case, because `mv` will only ever get passed filenames that start with a number.

Comment: @BlacklightShining - yes, I know, check the initial version of my answer. I removed it because, as you said, _in general, you should use -- in scripts_.

Answer (score 3):

Bjorn's solution seems like it should work, but another possibility would be to use find with a regex like `find -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[[:digit:]]{1,}(-[[:digit:]]{1,}){4}$'` then you can use that with either a `-exec mv {} first-class \;` or pipe to xargs or similar

Comment: This will also match files like `2-34` or `44-11-22-000-44-55-7-100` . Maybe if you adjust your regex to match _five numbers separated by four dashes_, e.g. `".*/[0-9]{1,}(-[0-9]{1,}){4}$"`.

Comment: Right you are don_crissti, updated to be more precise.  I was being sloppy, figuring there weren't a lot of other similar named files there, but that's often a dangerous assumption of course!

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `mv [0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* first-class` do the trick?

Comment: This won't work OK, it will also move files like `700-24-1-7-1-XYZ` and `44h-5c-88-9-2`

Comment: Gah, you're right, this is the usual confusion between wildcard patterns and regexps. [0-9]* in the shell means a digit followed by any number of characters, not 0 or more digits.

Comment: It does not work at all.